# Ansible variable conversion to int is ignored

Tags: kubernetes, service, ansible

With Ansible, I want to find which port is available in a range on a K8s cluster and use this port to expose a service temporary.

I'm able to find and extract the port but when I'm declaring the Nodeport using that port the tasks fail.

It seems that ansible is not converting my "port" variable to an int with the instruction {{ port|int }}.

```
- block:
    - name: List all ports in range 32200 to 32220
      wait_for:
        port: "{{ item|int }}"
        timeout: 1
        state: stopped
        msg: "Port {{ item }} is already in use"
      register: available_ports
      with_sequence: start=32200 end=32220
      ignore_errors: yes

    - name: extract first unused port from list
      set_fact:
        port: "{{ available_ports.results | json_query(\"[? state=='stopped'].port\") | first }}"
    
- debug:
        var: port
    
- name: Expose service as a nodeport service
  k8s:
    state: present
    definition:
      apiVersion: v1
      kind: Service
      metadata:
        name: "{{ namespace }}-service-nodeport"
        namespace: "{{ namespace }}"
      spec:
        type: NodePort
        selector:
          component: my-app
        ports:
          - protocol: TCP
            targetPort: 5432
            nodePort: "{{ port|int }}"
            port: 5432
```

This outputs the following:

```
TASK [../roles/my-role : debug] ***************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [127.0.0.1] => {
    "port": "32380"
}

TASK [../roles/my-role : Expose service as a nodeport service] *******************************************************************************************************************************************
fatal: [127.0.0.1]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "error": 400, "msg": "Failed to create object: b'{\"kind\":\"Status\",\"apiVersion\":\"v1\",\"metadata\":{},\"status\":\"Failure\",\"message\":\"Service in version \\\\\"v1\\\\\" cannot be handled as a Service: v1.Service.Spec: v1.ServiceSpec.Ports: []v1.ServicePort: v1.ServicePort.NodePort: readUint32: unexpected character: \\\\ufffd, error found in #10 byte of ...|dePort\\\\\": \\\\\"32380\\\\\", \\\\\"p|..., bigger context ...|rotocol\\\\\": \\\\\"TCP\\\\\", \\\\\"targetPort\\\\\": 5432, \\\\\"nodePort\\\\\": \\\\\"32380\\\\\", \\\\\"port\\\\\": 5432}]}}|...\",\"reason\":\"BadRequest\",\"code\":400}\\n'", "reason": "Bad Request", "status": 400}
```

If I set the nodeport to a fix value such as 32800, it works.

Comment: Does it work if you remove the double-quotes from the `nodePort` line?

Comment: [`\\\ufffd`](https://codepoints.net/U+FFFD) sure is suspiciously a unicode character in what shouldn't have any such thing; are you giving us the whole story?

Comment: @jkinkead that won't work with vanilla ansible, since jinja2 uses `{{` as it "echo" syntax, but YAML uses `{` to begin a sub-object (just like json) so they have to be quoted

Comment: @mdaniel I completed the story.  My objectif is to dynamically find a free port in a range and use it to deploy a temporary nodePort.

Comment: A classic example of the XY problem, you don't need to do that; if you just say `type: NodePort`, then kubernetes will use its built-in accounting of _allocated_ NodePorts per `port:` per `Service` and not assign a conflicting one. You can then fetch the _assigned_ `NodePort` from the resulting `Service` for use in your playbook, if that's what you're trying to do

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65410004/2574719) might work for you, or use a Jinja template.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is not ur case but I solved my issue.

I had the variable inside a map where all the vars where strings...
Since k8s is written in GO you can't have multi type maps, so try moving your variable to another place.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).